# How do I resolve No Modules found matching spec when running pdoc (in Windows)?

Tags: python-3.x, modulenotfounderror, pdoc

I'm trying to run the simple demo script from [pdoc](https://pdoc.dev/) documentation in windows from the command line. Using python 3.11.4 with virtualenv and PYTHONPATH set to folder in question.

```
"""
A small `pdoc` example.
"""

class Dog:
    """ (dog) """
    name: str
    """The name of our dog."""
    friends: list["Dog"]
    """The friends of our dog."""

    def __init__(self, name: str):
        """Make a Dog without any friends (yet)."""
        self.name = name
        self.friends = []

    def bark(self, loud: bool = True):
        """*woof*"""
```

> pdoc  .\demo.py

I get the following error message(s)

```
Warn: pdoc cannot load 'pdoc' because a module with the same name is already imported in pdoc's Python process. pdoc will document the loaded module from C:\Pythons\virtenvs\glogger11.4\Lib\site-packages\pdoc\__init__.py instead.
Warn: Cannot find spec for pdoc.demo (from .\demo.py):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Pythons\virtenvs\glogger11.4\Lib\site-packages\pdoc\extract.py", line 62, in walk_specs
    raise ModuleNotFoundError(modname)
ModuleNotFoundError: pdoc.demo
 (C:\Pythons\virtenvs\glogger11.4\Lib\site-packages\pdoc\web.py:105)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Pythons\virtenvs\glogger11.4\Scripts\pdoc.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Pythons\virtenvs\glogger11.4\Lib\site-packages\pdoc\__main__.py", line 207, in cli
    httpd = pdoc.web.DocServer((opts.host, opts.port or 8080), opts.modules)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Pythons\virtenvs\glogger11.4\Lib\site-packages\pdoc\web.py", line 105, in __init__
    module_names = extract.walk_specs(specs)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Pythons\virtenvs\glogger11.4\Lib\site-packages\pdoc\extract.py", line 85, in walk_specs
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: No modules found matching spec: .\demo.py
(
```

Answer (score 1):

> Warn: pdoc cannot load 'pdoc' because a module with the same name is already imported in pdoc's Python process. pdoc will document the loaded module from C:\Pythons\virtenvs\glogger11.4\Lib\site-packages\pdoc_*init*_.py instead.

I think this error message gives it away. Are you running pdoc in a folder named `pdoc`, and do you also have an `__init__.py` in that folder? If there is an `__init__.py` file, pdoc will treat the current directory as a module.

Comment: Of course, your suggestion worked.  I'm a little embarrassed I didn't pick up on it.  (Can't see the forest from the trees?).  Anyway, thank you.